# Releasing the UI to update with deferreds

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I like the look of then/deferred/promises but I'd like long-running processing to not block the UI rendering. In the following code example, I like the style of `fill2` but prefer the behavior of `fill3`. Nested `setTimeout`'s are ugly. Web workers may be an option, but there is quite a bit of overhead and compatibility issues with them. Is there a way to do this simply?

I made a living clickable example at http://jsfiddle.net/ubershmekel/8mtbM/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>First</h1>
<script>
var setTimeoutDelay = 50; // I noticed that 0 releases the UI in IE10 but not fully in Chrome31 or FF25.

var time = function() {
    return (new Date).getTime();
}

busy = function() {
    var start = time();
    while (time() - start < 2000) {

    }
    console.log('dn ' + time());
}

pin = function(i) {
    $('body').append($('<h1>' + i + '</h1>'));
}

clear = function() {
    $('body').html('');
}

fill = function() {
    busy();
    pin(1);
    busy();
    pin(2);
    busy();
    pin(3);
}

fill2 = function() {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.then(function() {
        busy();
        pin(1);
    }).then(function() {
        busy();
        pin(2);
    }).then(function() {
        busy();
        pin(3);
    });
    def.resolve();
}

fill3 = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        busy();
        pin(1);
        setTimeout(function() {
            busy();
            pin(2);
            setTimeout(function() {
                busy();
                pin(3);
            }, setTimeoutDelay);
        }, setTimeoutDelay);
    }, setTimeoutDelay);
}


$(function() {
    var start = function() {
        clear();
        setTimeout(fill1);
        //setTimeout(fill2);
        //setTimeout(fill3);
    };

    setTimeout(start);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason fill3 allows the rendering to continue is you're using setTimeout, which acts like an asynchronous method in that it waits for a few seconds before continuing. Unfortunately, the only way to replicate that with deferreds is to also use setTimeout. The best solution is to fix whatever `busy` is representing so that it doesn't block rendering.

Comment: `busy` is a few long running functions, downloading a file, parsing it, then recursively traversing a graph. Each one of those may be a few seconds.

Comment: Right, but that shouldn't be blocking rendering. If it is, then it can likely be optimized or modified in such a way that it doesn't block rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a jQuery plugin I call `.thenst`. It's just a `then` that to proceed to whatever's next uses `setTimeout`. I'm not sure how useful it is for humanity in general but it solves this problem.

Here's a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ubershmekel/8mtbM/2/

The plugin code

```
(function ($) {
    /*
    Give deferred objects a `.thenst` function which chains like `then`
    but adds a `setTimeout` in between to allow for UI responsiveness.
    This is extra useful for chaining ~1-second long functions.
    */

    var origDeferred = $.Deferred;
    $.Deferred = function (func) {
        var thenst = function (fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress) {
            var newDef = $.Deferred();
            var args;
            var runsAfterSetTimeout = function () {
                newDef.then(fnDone);
                newDef.resolveWith(newDef, args);
            };
            def.then(function () {
                args = arguments;
                setTimeout(runsAfterSetTimeout, 0)
            }, fnFail, fnProgress);
            return newDef;
        };

        // Hooking jQuery's Deferred is hard because we have to modify Deferred()
        // and Deferred.promise() though a Deferred has all the methods of a promise.
        // It would be nicer if we could only extend the `promise  ` object.
        var def = origDeferred(func);
        def.thenst = thenst;
        var origPromise = def.promise;
        def.promise = function (obj) {
            obj = origPromise(obj);
            obj.thenst = thenst;
            return obj;
        }
        return def;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

And here's the sample page with the example of it working just in case jsfiddle ever fizzles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Notice how fillLinear/fillDefer don't let you see the numbers were cleared. The button doesn't become depressed. And you don't see the numbers updating as they're pinned. fillSetTimeout works well but is hard to read and write. The performance difference between fillSetTimeout and fillThenst is inconsisntent and is probably garbage-collection and redrawing-timing related.</p>
<button onclick="fillLinear()">fillLinear</button>
<button onclick="fillDefer()">fillDefer</button>
<button onclick="fillSetTimeout()">fillSetTimeout</button>
<button onclick="fillThenst()">fillThenst</button>
<div id="panel"></div>


<script>

(function ($) {
    /*
    Give deferred objects a `.thenst` function which chains like `then`
    but adds a `setTimeout` in between to allow for UI responsiveness.
    This is extra useful for chaining ~1-second long functions.
    */

    var origDeferred = $.Deferred;
    $.Deferred = function (func) {
        var thenst = function(fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress) {
            var newDef = $.Deferred();
            var args;
            var runsAfterSetTimeout = function() {
                /*if ($.isFunction(fnDone)) {
                    // call the function and report it's done
                    fnDone.apply(newDef, args);
                } else {
                    // fnDone should be a promise object like:
                    //     $.Deferred().thenst($.ajax());
                    // We want to trigger that promise to run, I'm not sure if this is the way to do that.
                    // Though this point is kinda moot for $.ajax as it would fire off at instantiation.
                    newDef.then(fnDone);*/
                newDef.then(fnDone);
                newDef.resolveWith(newDef, args);
            };
            def.then(function() { args = arguments; setTimeout(runsAfterSetTimeout, 0) }, fnFail, fnProgress);
            return newDef;
        };

        // Hooking jQuery's Deferred is hard because we have to modify Deferred()
        // and Deferred.promise() though a Deferred has all the methods of a promise.
        // It would be nicer if we could only extend the `promise  ` object.
        var def = origDeferred(func);
        def.thenst = thenst;
        var origPromise = def.promise;
        def.promise = function(obj) {
            obj = origPromise(obj);
            obj.thenst = thenst;
            return obj;
        }
        return def;
    };

}(jQuery));


var setTimeoutDelay = 50; // I noticed that 0 releases the UI in IE10 but not fully in Chrome31 or FF25.

var time = function() {
    return (new Date).getTime();
}

busy = function() {
    var start = time();
    while (time() - start < 1000) {

    }
    console.log('dn ' + time());
}

pin = function(i) {
    $('#panel').append($('<h1>' + i + '</h1>'));
}

bclear = function() {
    $('#panel').html('');
}

fillLinear = function() {
    bclear();
    pin(0);
    busy();
    pin(1);
    busy();
    pin(2);
    busy();
    pin(3);
}

fillDefer = function() {
    bclear();
    pin(0);
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.then(function() {
        busy();
        pin(1);
    }).then(function() {
        busy();
        pin(2);
    }).then(function() {
        busy();
        pin(3);
    });
    def.resolve();
}

fillSetTimeout = function() {
    bclear();
    pin(0);
    setTimeout(function() {
        busy();
        pin(1);
        setTimeout(function() {
            busy();
            pin(2);
            setTimeout(function() {
                busy();
                pin(3);
            }, setTimeoutDelay);
        }, setTimeoutDelay);
    }, setTimeoutDelay);
}

fillThenst = function() {
    bclear();
    pin(0);
    var def = $.Deferred();
    def.thenst(function() {
        busy();
        pin(1);
    }).thenst(function() {
        busy();
        pin(2);
    }).thenst(function() {
        busy();
        pin(3);
    });
    def.resolve();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS thenst stands for then-setTimeout. As uncreative as it sounds.